# python, how to quit while loop when answer is wrong

Tags: python, while-loop, exit

i just started with python. in my code i asked for the user age. if he is younger than 18 i want to quit the program and not just ask the question again.
how do i do this?

i tried break, breakpoint, quit, systemexit, system error..

```
a = 3
while a < 4:
    print ("age: ")
    age = input()

    age = int(age)



    if (age >= 18):
        print("welcome")
        a = a + 3
    else:
        print("too young")
        SystemExit
        exit
        break
        quit

print("oi")
```

the program asks the question again and again.

Comment: It seems like you are looking for `sys.exit()`. You need to `import sys` at the beginning for your program to be able to use it.

Comment: `break` is supposed to work and it works as I tested your code with proper indentation

Comment: I think you need to move the if block inside your while loop

Comment: Please try the Python documentation first before asking a question. Google is your friend.

Comment: Your indentation is wrong: the `if` must be a part of the loop.

Comment: The posted code doesn't run with a full Python compiler: the syntax checker rejects it because there's a `break` that's not in any loop.  If you're in an interpreter, it executes the infinite loop: the top 6 lines of your program are the entire loop.

Comment: sorry, i didnt paste the code right.

Comment: thanks @timakro that worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to control while with a **boolean** and make it **false** *if the value is less and **break**:*

```
check = True
while check:
    age = int(input("age: "))

    if (age < 18):
        print('too young')
        check = False
        break
    else:
        print("welcome")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement isn't indented properly. It needs to be under the while loop. If you want another way to continuously ask the user for their age and if they're too young then exit the program:

```
   import sys

   while True:    
       age = int(input('Enter your age'))

       if age < 18:
           sys.exit('You are too young')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to either use sys.exit() as other have suggested above, or you could try using a boolean value to be the condition for the 'while' loop.

```
oldEnough = True
while oldEnough == True:
    age = int(input("Age: "))
    if age > 17:
        print ("Welcome")
        oldEnough = True;
        a += 3

    elif age < 18:
        print ("Too young")
        oldEnough = False
        break; # just for good measure.
```

I hope this works for you. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

You may want to try something like this

```
while True:
    age = input("Input your age: ")
    age = int(age)
    if age >= 18:
        print("welcome")
        break
    else:
        print("too young")
        exit(0)  # exit code 0 means everything is ok, exit with a diff code to indicate an issue
```